# QTablewidget first row occupying more space

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I am developing an application using PyQt4 and Qt4Designer, I have designed from designer and generated python code. As you can see in the below image, when I am adding first row, it's occupying whole layout space, but later rows are of fixed width.

Image showing the actual problem

[image]

Here's my code...

main.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'pyqt.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(983, 600)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(900, 600))
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 90, 675, 441))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayoutWidget"))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, -1, -1, -1)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(589, 439))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tableWidget"))
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 20, 85, 27))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.AddTask = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.AddTask.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 20, 85, 27))
        self.AddTask.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("AddTask"))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.AddTask.raise_()
        self.tableWidget.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Stockroom Adidas", None))
        self.tableWidget.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>This is where you can add new jobs</p></body></html>", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SKU", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Size", None))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Status", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Lobby</span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.AddTask.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add Task", None))
```

app.py

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QRegExp
from PyQt4.QtGui import QHeaderView
from PyQt4.QtGui import QTableWidgetItem

from main import Ui_MainWindow, QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from newtask import Ui_NewTask


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        resolution = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        # positioning window to center
        self.move((resolution.width() / 2) - (self.frameSize().width() / 2),
                  (resolution.height() / 2) - (self.frameSize().height() / 2))
        self.setupUi(self)
        # Customizing Columns in Table
        rowHeader = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
        rowHeader.setResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        rowHeader.setResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        rowHeader.setResizeMode(2, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        rowHeader.setResizeMode(3, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        # self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
        # self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()
        # When clicked on Add Task button

        def showDialog():
            newdialog = NewTask(parent=self)
            newdialog.show()
            if newdialog.exec_():
                # adding rows to the table
                for i in range(len(newdialog.data)):
                    currentrow = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
                    self.tableWidget.insertRow(currentrow)
                    for j in range(len(newdialog.data[i])):
                        self.tableWidget.setItem(currentrow, j, newdialog.data[i][j])

        self.AddTask.clicked.connect(showDialog)

        header = self.tableWidget.verticalHeader()
        header.setResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        # header.setDefaultSectionSize(12)
```

I have another class which inherits QDialog which has lot code, don't want to make this complex, not posting it... you can seee that when the AddTask button is clicked I am connecting the signal to showDialog function. There I am adding rows, I don't know where I am doing wrong, I have tried all the below possible ways.

```
self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()
```

OR

```
header.setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

OR

```
header.setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Fixed)
```

OR

```
self.tableWidget.rowHeight(20)
```

OR

```
self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()
```

None of them worked... Please help...

EDIT1:

When I try to add rows in qtdesigner, facing the same problem, attaching the image here

QtDesigner

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be `self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)` is causing problem.